# Hello I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL so I trying to create a one to one relationship between the tables account and bank_account

Tags: postgresql

I tried using a foreign key, but it still shows them as being separate and not connected is there something I'm missing here, my goal was to originally link the persons name to the account_balance.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts ( 
    id SERIAL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR (50),
    username VARCHAR (50),
    password VARCHAR (500),
    account_Type VARCHAR (10),
    bday VARCHAR (50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );




CREATE TABLE bank_account(
    id SERIAL,
    account_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    account_balance INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT bank_users
        FOREIGN KEY (id)
            REFERENCES accounts(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO accounts (
    first_name,
    last_name,
    username,
    password,
    account_Type,
    bday)
    VALUES ('bob', 'john', 'bob@gmail.com', crypt('bob1',gen_salt('bf')),'Manager', '01/01/1985'),
    ('Tom', 'lin', 'tom@gmail.com', 'tom1', 'Manager', '5/23/1990');





INSERT INTO bank_account(
    account_number,
    account_balance)
    VALUES ('1234', '50000'),('4332', '100000');
```

Comment: "*it still shows them as being separate and not connected*" - what tool are you using that is "showing" connections? (And between what?)

Comment: What does one-to-one relationship mean exactly, what are the cardinalities of the relationship? Can there be one without the other?